# Example of dynamic component creation with server side dependency

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I was reading this article: [Dynamic Component Creation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)

> To use $A.createComponent(), we need the component definition. If we
> don’t have the definition already on the client, the framework makes a
> server trip to get it.

I'm not able to understand this even after trying hard ?Can some one give any example of what is meant by server side dependency for component definition? Example given in article doesn't show that and I'm not able to find any example on search.

Please note :  I know Pros and Cons of dynamically creating components and even using lightning-aura  componets when LWC is in place. This is just for my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else run into this confusion, server side dependency means presence of anything for which values needs to be fetched from server, for e.g. presence of custom labels in markup. For dynamic component creation, this means component can't be created on client side as it needs server trip.